# What can we say about the pointwise limit of uniformly continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

A uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. In other words, if $f_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions that uniformly converges to $f$, then $f$ is continuous.

However, I'm wondering what if $f_n$ is a sequence of uniformly continuous functions that converge pointwise to a function $f$? Can we say anything about $f$? Does it have to be continuous, uniformly continuous, continuous almost everywhere, ... or something else?

Comment: observe that any continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous, therefore the assumption that every function in a sequence is uniformly continuous doesn't say very much.

Comment: In light of what @Targon said, you may want to look at [*Baire one functions*](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/huh.pdf) by Johnny Hu and [*Functions of Baire class one*](https://math.ucsd.edu/_files/undergraduate/honors-program/honors-program-presentations/2012-2013/Siuyung_Fung_Honors_Thesis.pdf) by Siuyung Fung.

Comment: *(Links in my previous comment no longer work)* In light of what @Targon said, you may want to look at [*Baire One Functions*](https://web.archive.org/web/20190424032213/https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/huh.pdf) by Johnny Hu and [*Functions of Baire Class One*](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506183250/https://math.ucsd.edu/_files/undergraduate/honors-program/honors-program-presentations/2012-2013/Siuyung_Fung_Honors_Thesis.pdf) by Siuyung Fung.

Comment: updating outdated links in a forum post is a cool move! thanks for doing that.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you. I appreciate the dedication!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers are no, no, and no. Take any compact $K\subset [0,1]$ such that $K$ contains no rational and $m(K)>0.$ Define

$$f_n(x) = (1-d(x,K))^n.$$

Then $f_n\to \chi_K$ pointwise everywhere in $[0,1].$ Since $\chi_K$ is discontinuous at each point of $K,$ we have our example.

Comment: Hi, sorry, what is $d(x,K)$?

Comment: @twosigma It is the distance from $x$ to $K.$

Answer (score 2):

Pointwise convergence does not say much, because most of the important things (derivative, integral, continuity) requires uniform convergence.

There is one example I can think of where pointwise convergence can help us: Dini's theorm:

> Let $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise in a **closed** interval $[a,b]$. If $\forall x\in[a,b] , f_n(x)$ is monotone and $f_n, f$ are continuous than $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformaly.