# Is a continuous function necessarily the pointwise limit of a sequence of uniformly continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity, pointwise-convergence

The pointwise limit of a sequence of uniformly continuous functions [needn't be continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695815/what-can-we-say-about-the-pointwise-limit-of-uniformly-continuous-functions). I've been wondering about the converse:

> Is a continuous function $f$ necessarily the pointwise limit of some sequence of uniformly continuous functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?

I'm having trouble establishing or disproving this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R$, then the answer is yes. The proof is quite easy: let $f_n: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by
$$f_n(x)= \begin{cases} 
f(-n) & x<-n \\
f(x) & -n \le x \le n \\ f(n) & x>n \end{cases}$$
these are uniformly continuous and they pointwise converge to $f$.

Comment: Why are the $f_n$ uniformly continuous (in $-n\leq x\leq n$)? We only know that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: That's because on a compact set every continuous function is uniformly continuous. If you extend as a constant function outside the boundary of $[-n,n]$ it remains uniformly continuous.

Comment: Of course, thanks for the clarification.